# How to get all values of a specific key in array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have array of objects like this

```
const object1 = {
  a: 'somestring',
  b: 42,
  c: false
};
const object2 = {
  a: 'somestring2',
  b: 42,
  c: false
};
const object3 = {
  a: 'somestring3',
  b: 42,
  c: false
};
const arr = [object1,object2,object3]
```

i want to get all the values of 'a' key.
so result be

> `['somestring','somestring2','somestring3']`

I tried Object.values() but it gets me all values of all keys, which is not the desired output.

Comment: Looks like a good read: https://contactmentor.com/javascript-map-array-of-objects/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function:

```
const arr = [object1,object2,object3].map(({a}) => (a))
```

An example:

```js
const object1 = {
  a: 'somestring',
  b: 42,
  c: false
};
const object2 = {
  a: 'somestring2',
  b: 42,
  c: false
};
const object3 = {
  a: 'somestring3',
  b: 42,
  c: false
};
const arr = [object1,object2,object3].map(({a}) => (a))
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: it returns [{a: 'somestring'},{a: 'somestring2'},
 {a: 'somestring3'}] 

i want it to return ['somestring','somestring2','somestring3']

Comment: @Abdel-Rahman please, see my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `const arr = [object1.a, object2.a, object3.a]`? That might work

Comment: Nothing in JavaScript is encapsulated by default.  There are ways to do it, but without those explicit techniques, all properties and methods are available.

Also, while your answer would produce the correct result, I believe they wanted a general solution that doesn't require explicitly knowing about all the elements of the array.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).